# EOL for Spring Boot 2.3.X and Spring Cloud Hoxton.SR6

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

When is the planned EOL for Spring Boot 2.3.X and Spring Cloud Hoxton.SR6?

I found 2 links:

1. https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud:

**Spring Cloud Dalston, Edgware, Finchley, and Greenwich have all reached end of life status and are** no longer supported.

2. https://spring.io/blog/2019/12/23/spring-cloud-roadmap-and-hoxton-and-greenwich-maintenance-and-eol-announcements

Spring Cloud Hoxton
Finchley was first released in June 2018. Therefore, Hoxton, a minor release of the Finchley release train, will be supported until the end of June 2021 with regular releases. **Starting in July 2021 Hoxton will enter a special maintenance period where only critical bug fixes and security patches will be released until the end of December 2021.**

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/wiki/Supported-Versions standard Open source support ended in June 2021. Security and commercial support until March 2022

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Supported-Versions

> Spring Boot releases are usually marked end of life 27 months after they were released.

And here: https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support

> | Branch | Initial Release | End of Support | End Commercial Support * |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | ... | ... | ... | ... |
> | **2.3.x** | 2020-05-15 | 2021-05-20 | 2022-08-20 |
> | ... |  |  |  |

And from (thx, @spencergibb): https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/wiki/Supported-Versions#supported-releases

> Hoxton was released in November 2019 and will be **actively maintained until June 30, 2021** (Supporting the Spring Boot 2.2.x and 2.3.x lines. Hoxton.SR5 added support for Spring Boot 2.3.x). **If critical bugs or security issues arise after that period, they will be patched until Mar 26, 2022.**